# openiddict asp.net core OpenIdConnectRequest parameter

Tags: openiddict

I need OpenIdConnectRequest class inharit and add device id and a extra parameter. How can i add this 2 extra parameter in OpenIdConnectRequest class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var stringParameter = (string) request["string_parameter"];
var longParameter = (long) request["long_parameter"];
```